# How to share LSTM unit for 2 separate input in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Assume I have 2 input `q` and `a`, how to make the 2 inputs share 1 `LSTM` cell? Now part of my code as belows

```
def lstmnets(self, sequence, seq_len):
    seq_embeds = self.embeds(sequence)

    # lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.hidden_size)
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(self.hidden_size)
    init_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
    lstm_out, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, seq_embeds, initial_state=init_state, sequence_length=seq_len)
    return lstm_out

def inference(self, q, a, q_len, a_len):
    with tf.variable_scope('lstmnets') as scope:
        query_rep = self.lstmnets(q, q_len)
        scope.reuse_variables()
        title_rep = self.lstmnets(a, a_len)
```

But for this codes, My structure have 2 stacked `LSTM` as following figure. How can I just use one `LSTM` for both? In addition, how can I initial the LSTM weights and add them to `histogram`? so far, I find no related tutorials for this. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine as it uses scope.reuse_variable() to share the LSTM weights. The best way is to check is by printing the variables in the graph and verify whether the lstm_cell is declared only once. So in your inference function print the variable names:

```
def inference(self, q, a, q_len, a_len):
  with tf.variable_scope('lstmnets') as scope:
    query_rep = self.lstmnets(q, q_len)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    title_rep = self.lstmnets(a, a_len)
  for v in tf.global_variables():
    print(v.name)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a try..Do you know where can I initial LSTM cell weights?

Comment: I print the name, seems there are just one LSTM as the params are `lstmnets/embeddings:0
lstmnets/rnn/lstm_cell/kernel:0
lstmnets/rnn/lstm_cell/bias:0`, so confused why the graphs have 2 stacked rnn...

Comment: Or the stacked LSTM is exactly same and the line between them representing `share`? It is kindly weird compared to CNNs share...

Comment: Yes the stacked LSTM showing in the graphs should be same. Check their names there as well.

Comment: I just deep dive into the graphs. The line indicates 2 tensors: `kernel` and `bias`. I think they are the shared `W`&`U` and `b`.